# Intermediate values for continuous band legend in layout

Tags: qgis, layouts

Is it possible to add intermediate values in the layout for a continuous band of values? QGIS by default gives me the beginning and the end. I would like to avoid adding them by hand

For example I want to obtain something like that:

[image]

QGIS 3.28.9-Firenze

Comment: Your question is confusing. What is it that you want that is different from the default? Do you want horizontal red bars and the number 130 surrounded by a box? Or is it something else?

Comment: This behavior was changed in QGIS sometime to the one shown in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/459217/63384). You can increase the number of classes or you can add the intervals manually in the layout.